# Qt5 | Переходы между формами

Tags: c++, qt

Есть два класса, пусть будет Форма 1 и Форма 2, который созданы в Qt desinger. Я хочу их завязать между собой.
в заголовочный файл Формы 1 подключаю заголовок формы 2, делаю указатель `Form2 *test;` в самой же форме создаю `test = new Form2();` 
Всё работает, теперь можно добавить кнопку и переходить на Форму 2 или передавать какие либо данные из Формы 1 в Форму 2. 
НО! Если я хочу подключить Форму 3 и добавить в заголовок форму 2 и попытаться сделать вызов Формы 2, то получаю ошибки "непонятный тип". 
Добавлял в заголовочные файлы дополнительные строки `class Form2;` 
Всё компилируется, но при этом программа просто выдает критическую ошибку.

Схема такая, если я двигаюсь по формам в одном направлении, то все работает.

1->2->3->..->10

Если, я пытаюсь двигаться в разных направлениях.

1->2->3->4->2 = Не работает.

1->2->3->1    = Не работает.

1->2->3->4->1 = Не работает.

Comment: Судя по всему, вы забыли передать адреса родителей в дочерние объекты. То есть у родителей указатель есть, а у детей - нет, поэтому и обращаться можно лишь вниз по иерархии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можно небольшой пример добавления адресов?

Comment: Передавайте указатель на родителя через аргумент конструктора: сhildPtr = new MyForm(parentPtr);

Comment: И, кстати, с 99% вероятностью вы наследуетесь от QObject, в котором уже реализованы объектные иерархии. Можно почитать в [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)

Comment: Ребят, напишите пожалуйста развернутый ответ.  Я даже не думал, что это такая сложная проблема "связь между формами". Это должно как-то просто всё делаться.

Comment: ОК, если вы не хотите объектные иерархии Qt, то ваша задача - сделать два класса с членами-указателями и позаботиться, чтобы они указывали друг на друга. То есть в конструктор ребенка можно сразу передавать адрес родителя. Всё. Если вам это кажется сложным и нужен готовый код, то нужно читать книжку про самые основы C++: про конструкторы, про инициализацию членов, про указатели и ссылки, чтобы был прочный фундамент знаний. Поднимайте завесу магии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для двухсторонней передачи данных между объектами (тем более между несколькими объектами) лучше не использовать передачу указателя на соседа, а пользоваться механизмом сигналов и слотов. При это `connect` нужно будет делать только в одном окне из пары и отпадет необходимость в перекрестных включениях заголовочных файлов

---

Допустим, мы имеем две формы - Form1 и Form2. В обоих классах описываем сигналы для отправки данных:

```
signals:
    void sendData(QVariant variant);
```

и слоты для получения данных:

```
public slots:
    voiв recieveData(QVariant variant);
```

В конструкторе Form1 соединяем сигналы отправки данных со слотами получения (допустим, что объект класса Form2 объявлен в классе Form1 и называется form2):

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QVariant), form2, SLOT(recieveData(QVariant));  //отправка данных из Form1 в Form2
connect(form2, SIGNAL(sendData(QVariant), this, SLOT(recieveData(QVariant));  //отправка данных обратно из Form2 в Form1
```

Теперь если мы в Form1 испустим сигнал с какими-то данными, в Form2 будет вызывана функция получения данных:
    emit sendData(QVariant("MyCoolData");

И наоборот, для пересылки данных из Form2 в Form1 испускаем сигнал из Form2 аналогичным способом.

Будьте внимательны, чтобы испускание сигналов не привело к бесконечному цикличному вызову слотов.

Подключение дополнительных окон делается по тому же принципу - объявляем сигналы для отправки и слоты для получения в обоих классах, подключение делаем в том, в котором является "родителем".

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример. Как это реализовывается на практике?

Comment: @Renovacio тредактировал ответ, добавил пример

Comment: Спасибо большое! )